# String Concatenation Errors in ejs / node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

I am having trouble loading a custom font while using ejs.  I don't think the issue is with the font itself, but if you are interested, the source is:

https://github.com/andrewgioia/Keyrune

I think problem is with the way the html tag is rendered when concatenating the class using ejs.

the ejs doc:

```
<body>

<i class="ss ss-6x"> </i> 
// default symbol correct size


<i class="ss ss-6x ss-lea"> </i> 
// correct symbol/size 
//html renders as <i class="ss ss-6x ss-lea"> </i>

<i class=<%= "ss ss-6x ss-" + sets[0].setCode %>> </i> 
// default symbol shows up in wrong font size
// html renders as <i class="ss" ss-6x ss-lea> </i> 

<i class=<%= "ss " + "ss-6x " + "ss-" + sets[0].setCode%> > </i> 
// default symbol shows up in wrong font size
// html still renders as <i class="ss" ss-6x ss-lea> </i> 


<% console.log(sets[0].setCode); %> 
// prints as 'lea' 


</body>
```

node route (no issues here):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  con.query('SELECT * FROM mtgSets', function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    sets = rows;
    console.log(sets[0].setCode); //prints as lea 
    res.render('test', {sets: sets});
  });
});
```

Solution: quotes go around the "<%= %>" brackets!

```
<i class="<%= 'ss ss-6x ss-' + sets[0].setCode %>" > </i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried formatting your html consistently - you seem to have a bit of a mismatch with your single and double quotes and not everything has a start or end quote.

I tend to use double quotes with the HTML side and single quotes with the JS side.

So something like:

`<i class=<%= 'ss ' + 'ss-6x ' + 'ss-' + sets[0].setCode%> > </i>`

Becomes

`<i class="<%= 'ss ' + 'ss-6x ' + 'ss-' + sets[0].setCode%>" > </i>`

And

`<i class=<%= "ss ss-6x ss-" + sets[0].setCode %>> </i>`

Becomes

`<i class="<%= 'ss ss-6x ss-' + sets[0].setCode %>"> </i>`

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know you could put quotes around the <% %>.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jane - you're welcome. It's a common mistake that we all do far more often than we like :)